# how to get url with different ids in android (async task)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-asynctask

EDIT: Found the solution to my problem.
The json string output returned the wrong url for my local images.

i am barely new to android and struggle with asyncTask.

What i want is to get the corresponding image to a marker on a map.
every entry on this map has its own image which has to be loaded from server via json.

the image load works fine but i dont get the right workflow to get the image i need for one entry.

by now i have one solution to load an async task in a for-loop, but this cant be the right way because the app refuses to go on after 43 tasks and stops with 
"ECONNECTION TIMEOUT"

so how can get the asynctask out of the loop?

hope anyone can help? thank you!

here is my code:

public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

JSONArray contentJson;

String contentId;
String imageJsonUrl;
String userId;
Bitmap bmp;
LatLng latLng;
Marker m;
HashMap<Marker, String> hashMap;

int k = 0;

// check value for Request check
final int MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    if(this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            try {
                contentJson = new JSONArray(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("contentJson"));
               // Log.v("TESTITEST", contentJson.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("EXCEPTION", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_maps, menu);
    return true;
}

public LatLng getLatLngPosition() {
    return new LatLng(0, 0);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    //Ask for Permission. If granted show my Location
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Check Permissions Now
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // permission has been granted, continue as usual
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            LatLng selectedLocation = place.getLatLng();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(selectedLocation, 10f));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("PlaceSelectorError", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    LatLng bonn = new LatLng(50.7323, 7.1847);
    LatLng cologne = new LatLng(50.9333333, 6.95);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bonn).title("Marker in Bonn"));

    // hash map for saving content id with marker
    hashMap = new HashMap<Marker, String>();

    if(contentJson != null) {

        if (this.getIntent().getStringExtra("contentId") == null) {
            // show all contents of my friends
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < contentJson.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonInfo = contentJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray contents = jsonInfo.getJSONArray("content");
                    // Log.v("contentslength", String.valueOf(contents.length()));

                    //get all contents of one user
                    for (int j = 0; j < contents.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject eachcontent = contents.getJSONObject(j);
                        //Log.v("eachcontent", eachcontent.toString());
                        JSONObject location = eachcontent.getJSONObject("Location");
                        String contentId = eachcontent.getString("id");
                        String contentTitle = eachcontent.getString("title");
                        userId = eachcontent.getString("user_id");
                        latLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(location.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(location.getString("longitude")));
                        new MapImageLoadTask("http://192.168.63.35:1234/rest_app_users/getImage/", userId, contentId, contentTitle, latLng).execute();


                        Log.v("contentTitle", contentTitle);
                        //Log.v("m", m.toString());
                        //m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(contentTitle).position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(location.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(location.getString("longitude")))).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        else {
            // if we only want to see a specific content
            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < contentJson.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonInfo = contentJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray contents = jsonInfo.getJSONArray("content");

                    //get all contents of one user
                    for (int j = 0; j < contents.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject eachcontent = contents.getJSONObject(j);
                        JSONObject location = eachcontent.getJSONObject("Location");
                        if(eachcontent.getString("id").equals(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("contentId"))) {

                            String contentId = eachcontent.getString("id");
                            String contentTitle = eachcontent.getString("title");
                            userId = eachcontent.getString("user_id");
                            latLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(location.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(location.getString("longitude")));
                          //  Log.v("LATLNG", contentId);
                            new MapImageLoadTask("http://192.168.63.35:1234/rest_app_users/getImage/", userId, contentId, contentTitle, latLng).execute();

                            continue;

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("LOGEDILOG", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10f));
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            String id = hashMap.get(marker);
            Log.v("BITMAP", bmp.toString());
            try {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), contentDetailActivity.class);
                mapIntent.putExtra("contentId", id);
                mapIntent.putExtra("contentJson", contentJson.toString());
                mapIntent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                String filename = "profileImage.png";
                FileOutputStream stream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                //Cleanup
                stream.close();
                mapIntent.putExtra("image", filename);

                startActivity(mapIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Marker[] addMarkers() {
    return null;
}

/**
 *  lets you load Image from external source via url
 */
public class MapImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = MapImageLoadTask.class.getSimpleName();
    String url, userId, contentId, title;
    LatLng location;
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    public MapImageLoadTask(String url, String userId, String contentId, String title, LatLng location) {
        this.url = url;
        this.userId = userId;
        this.contentId = contentId;
        this.title = title;
        this.location = location;
    }

    private String getImageUrlFromJson(String imageJson) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject imageJsonOutput = new JSONObject(imageJson);
        imageJsonUrl = imageJsonOutput.getString("imageUrl");
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, imageJsonUrl);
        return imageJsonUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String imageJson = null;
        try {
            URL urlConnection = new URL(url + userId);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                    .openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            if (input == null) {
                // Nothing to do.
                //forecastJsonStr = null;
                return null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                // buffer for debugging.
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                return null;
            }

            imageJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            String jsonUrl = getImageUrlFromJson(imageJson);
            URL url = new URL(jsonUrl);
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            return bmp;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        k +=1;
        Log.v("COUNTER", String.valueOf(k));
        m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(title).position(location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
        hashMap.put(m, contentId);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hi friend, when new AsyncTask, you can put Id to constructor.

public ImageLoadTask(String id, String url, String userId) {
    this.url = url;
    this.id = id;
    this.userId = userId;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem maybe AsyncTask limitations. In android.os.AsyncTask.java you will see core size and blockingqueue size(128), should use counter for asynctask and debug it(Problem is, lots of async tasks or other).

> AsyncTask.java

```
public abstract class AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "AsyncTask";

    private static final int CPU_COUNT = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    private static final int CORE_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT + 1;
    private static final int MAXIMUM_POOL_SIZE = CPU_COUNT * 2 + 1;
    private static final int KEEP_ALIVE = 1;

    private static final ThreadFactory sThreadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {
        private final AtomicInteger mCount = new AtomicInteger(1);

        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            return new Thread(r, "AsyncTask #" + mCount.getAndIncrement());
        }
    };

    private static final BlockingQueue<Runnable> sPoolWorkQueue =
            new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(128);

...}
```

> Change Your Code Use Buffer(RequestData) And Use Only One Async Task. Update Market instance every publishProgress in onProgressUpdate

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

JSONArray contentJson;

String contentId;
String imageJsonUrl;
String userId;
Bitmap bmp;
LatLng latLng;
Marker m;
HashMap<Marker, String> hashMap;

int k = 0;

// check value for Request check
final int MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    if(this.getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            try {
                contentJson = new JSONArray(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("contentJson"));
               // Log.v("TESTITEST", contentJson.toString());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("EXCEPTION", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_maps, menu);
    return true;
}

public LatLng getLatLngPosition() {
    return new LatLng(0, 0);
}

/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;

    //Ask for Permission. If granted show my Location
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // Check Permissions Now
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MapsActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                MY_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else {
        // permission has been granted, continue as usual
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            LatLng selectedLocation = place.getLatLng();
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(selectedLocation, 10f));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Status status) {
            // TODO: Handle the error.
            Log.i("PlaceSelectorError", "An error occurred: " + status);
        }
    });

    LatLng bonn = new LatLng(50.7323, 7.1847);
    LatLng cologne = new LatLng(50.9333333, 6.95);
    //mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(bonn).title("Marker in Bonn"));

    // hash map for saving content id with marker
    hashMap = new HashMap<Marker, String>();

    if(contentJson != null) {

        if (this.getIntent().getStringExtra("contentId") == null) {
            // show all contents of my friends
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < contentJson.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonInfo = contentJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray contents = jsonInfo.getJSONArray("content");
                    // Log.v("contentslength", String.valueOf(contents.length()));

                    //get all contents of one user
                    for (int j = 0; j < contents.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject eachcontent = contents.getJSONObject(j);
                        //Log.v("eachcontent", eachcontent.toString());
                        JSONObject location = eachcontent.getJSONObject("Location");
                        String contentId = eachcontent.getString("id");
                        String contentTitle = eachcontent.getString("title");
                        userId = eachcontent.getString("user_id");
                        latLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(location.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(location.getString("longitude")));
                        new MapImageLoadTask("http://192.168.63.35:1234/rest_app_users/getImage/", userId, contentId, contentTitle, latLng).execute();


                        Log.v("contentTitle", contentTitle);
                        //Log.v("m", m.toString());
                        //m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(contentTitle).position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(location.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(location.getString("longitude")))).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bmp)));
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Exception", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        else {
            // if we only want to see a specific content
            try {
                List<RequestData> datas = new ArrayList<RequestData>();
                for (int i = 0; i < contentJson.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonInfo = contentJson.getJSONObject(i);

                    JSONArray contents = jsonInfo.getJSONArray("content");

                    //get all contents of one user


                    for (int j = 0; j < contents.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject eachcontent = contents.getJSONObject(j);
                        JSONObject location = eachcontent.getJSONObject("Location");
                        if(eachcontent.getString("id").equals(this.getIntent().getStringExtra("contentId"))) {

                            String contentId = eachcontent.getString("id");
                            String contentTitle = eachcontent.getString("title");
                            userId = eachcontent.getString("user_id");
                            latLng = new LatLng(Double.valueOf(location.getString("latitude")), Double.valueOf(location.getString("longitude")));
                          //  Log.v("LATLNG", contentId);


                              RequestData data = new RequestData();
                              data.url = "http://192.168.63.35:1234/rest_app_users/getImage/";
                              data.userId = userId;
                              data.contentId = contentId;
                              data.contentTitle = contentTitle;
                              data.latlng = latlng;
                              datas.add(data);
                            //new MapImageLoadTask("http://192.168.63.35:1234/rest_app_users/getImage/", userId, contentId, contentTitle, latLng).execute();

                            continue;

                        }
                    }
                }

                new MapImageLoadTask(datas).execute();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("LOGEDILOG", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 10f));
            mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
        }
    });

    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            String id = hashMap.get(marker);
            Log.v("BITMAP", bmp.toString());
            try {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), contentDetailActivity.class);
                mapIntent.putExtra("contentId", id);
                mapIntent.putExtra("contentJson", contentJson.toString());
                mapIntent.putExtra("userId", userId);
                String filename = "profileImage.png";
                FileOutputStream stream = context.openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                //Cleanup
                stream.close();
                mapIntent.putExtra("image", filename);

                startActivity(mapIntent);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Marker[] addMarkers() {
    return null;
}

/**
 *  lets you load Image from external source via url
 */

static class RequestData{

   public String url;
   public String userId;
   public String contentId;
   public String contentTitle;
   public LatLng latLng;
   public Bitmap bmp;
}


public class MapImageLoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, RequestData, Void> {
    private final String LOG_TAG = MapImageLoadTask.class.getSimpleName();
    BufferedReader reader = null;


   List<RequestData> dataSet;

    public MapImageLoadTask(List<RequestData> dataSet) {
        this.dataSet = dataSet;
    }

    private String getImageUrlFromJson(String imageJson) throws JSONException {

        JSONObject imageJsonOutput = new JSONObject(imageJson);
        imageJsonUrl = imageJsonOutput.getString("imageUrl");
        //Log.v(LOG_TAG, imageJsonUrl);
        return imageJsonUrl;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for(RequestData item : dataSet){
            String imageJson = null;
              try {
                  URL urlConnection = new URL(url + userId);
                  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection
                          .openConnection();
                  connection.setDoInput(true);
                  connection.connect();
                  InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                  if (input == null) {
                      // Nothing to do.
                      //forecastJsonStr = null;
                      return null;
                  }

                  reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

                  String line;
                  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                      // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                      // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                      // buffer for debugging.
                      buffer.append(line + "\n");
                  }

                  if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                      return null;
                  }

                  imageJson = buffer.toString();

              } catch (Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }


              try {
                  String jsonUrl = getImageUrlFromJson(imageJson);
                  URL url = new URL(jsonUrl);
                  bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                  // 
                  item.bmp = bmp;
                  publishProgress(item);
              }
              catch(Exception e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

         }



        return null;
    }

    protected void onPublishProgress(RequestData item){
        k +=1;
        Log.v("COUNTER", String.valueOf(k));
        m = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(item.title).position(item.location).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(item.bmp)));
        hashMap.put(m, contentId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


    }
}
}
```

Comment: yes that was my suggestion, too. i tested it and of 45 tasks (as there are 45 items to be shown) only 43 are outputted and then nothing happens for a long time. after that the ECONNECTION TIMEOUT is given in the logcat and the other 2 items are put out afterwards. don't know how to solve this

Comment: i'm still facing the same problem after item 43 with your solution. may it have something to do with the userId? because the last two items face a higher userid. doesn't make sense to me though.

Comment: Could you post your last two userid?

Comment: 130 and 146. though i dont understand why this could be a problem

Comment: Did you send request via browser with these parameters?

Comment: just checked the url request in the browser. i'm wondering if it has something to do with the url given as json from the request url. while all former images are the users facebook profile pictures in this case it's a different one. maybe the image can't be loaded locally, though the image is available in the resources as png.
to test if this is the problem i deleted the entry where the task stopped and everything worked. maybe its because of the file format?

Comment: or maybe because i send a BitmapFactory.decodeStream request to a local file...?